# PreFlush / OnFlush / PostFlush Symfony Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-eventdispatcher

How can we edit manually final SQL query before execution in Symfony / Doctrine?

I need to change value **MANUALLY** in SQL, ***i know i can edit it postPersist*** in entity, but i'm in a special case that this solution is not working in my schema .

A small idea :

```
public function preFlush/onFlush/PostFlush((PreFlushEventArgs/.../...)  $eventArgs) {
    $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {

        if($entity instanceof MyEntity) {
              //Change my value directly in SQL query

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to update a value within your *MyEntity* or is it another separate entity?

Comment: Also... What query are you trying to make? Can you edit your post with what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

```
public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        Events::preUpdate  => 'preUpdate',
    ];
}

public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
{
    $object = $args->getObject();

    if ($object instanceof MyEntity) {
        $object->setSomething('something');

        $meta = $args->getObjectManager()->getClassMetadata(MyEntity::class);
        $om->getUnitOfWork()->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $object);
    }
}
```